# Add new entry to the json file which has dup key

Tags: java, android, json

data.json , please note dup key city

```
{
  "type": "1",
  "city": [
  {

  "name": "c1",
  "dis": [
    {
      "dis_name": "d1"
    },
    {
      "dis_name": "d2"
    }
  ]
 }
],

"city": [
 {
  "name": "c2",
  "dis": [
    {
      "dis_name": "d3"
    },
    {
      "dis_name": "d2"
    }
  ]
 }
 ]
}
```

I think, because of dup key, JSON object built from the file is incorrect or has partial data.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(readJSONFromAsset());
```

readJSONFromAsset() copied from stackoverflow,

```
public String readJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("data.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

in obj, I see only partial data of json file. What is the best way to add following new entry in json file/object?

```
"city": [
{
 "name": "c3",
  "dis": [
 {
  "dis_name": "d5"
 },
 {
  "dis_name": "d2"
 }
 ]
}
]
```

Comment: add a different city key. keys are supposed to be unique mind you

Comment: What is the idea of "dis_name"?, maybe you can make an array "dis_name" with theirs values like: "dis_name": ["d5","d2"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a valid json document.  Valid json cannot have duplicate keys.  What happens when you try to treat it as JSON depends on how your deserializer chooses to implement it-  it could throw an exception, keep the first, or keep the last as common choices.

The only answer which will work is to fix your data so it is a valid json document.  I'd suggest turning city into an array.